# How does stacking the optional chaining (question-mark-dot) operator in Javascript behave?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

I ran these experiments in the Chrome console:

```
a = {}
   -> {}
```

```
a.n.n.n.n.n.n.n
   -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')
```

```
a?.n.n.n.n.n.n.n
   -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')
```

```
a?.n?.n.n.n.n.n.n
   -> undefined
```

Based on my understanding of that operator, I would have expected an error unless all "dots" have a preceding question mark: The subexpression `a?.n?.n` should result in undefined, and the subsequent `.n` should crash. However, after doing `?.n` two times, something seems to change and reading the property n of undefined seems to be okay, which is obviously nonsense. So something else is probably going on.

One might think that `?.` shortcuts the whole remaining expression when evaluated on undefined, but this cannot be the case either, otherwise a single `?.` should be sufficient to achieve that.

How exactly does `?.` behave, and how does that behaviour explain the results I'm getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the question:

> One might think that ?. shortcuts the whole remaining expression when evaluated on undefined

Yes, that is exactly what is happening. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

> The optional chaining (?.) operator accesses an object's property or calls a function. If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression **short circuits** and evaluates to undefined instead of throwing an error.

When you access `a.b.c` or `a?.b.c`

- `a` evaluates to the empty object
- `a.b` evaluates to undefined
- `a.b.c` throws an error because you are accessing `c` property from undefined.

Note that adding `?.` after `a` is unnecessary here because `a` is not nullish.

But, in case of `a?.b?.c.d` or `a.b?.c.d`

- `a` evaluates to an object and `a?.b` evaluates to undefined like before.
- When evaluating `a?.b?.c`: since `a.b` is undefined, it doesn't access the `c` property and short circuits here and returns undefined value for the entire expression

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the "Short Circuiting" chapter of the documentation, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> When using optional chaining with expressions, if the left operand is null or undefined, the expression will not be evaluated

Especially the sentence following that first paragraph:

> Subsequent property accesses will not be evaluated either.

So this is documented behavior, and it does well explain the behavior you see, because in your example

```
a?.n.n.n.n.n.n.n -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'n')
```

`a` is not undefined, and thus the first `?.` is evaluated to `a` and then the next expression the runtime sees, is `a.n.n`.